# php search form with pagination

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, pagination

im having the following issue with some php/javascript code. I have 3 pages: `index.php` | `result.php` and `pagination.php`. this is the code(really simple here):

**index.php**

```
<form action="result2.php" method="get" id="search">
<input type="text" id="query" name="query"/>
<input type="submit" id="mainsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

result.php gets the data of the form, but my problem is the following: in result.php i use pagination, and i have a third page called pagination.php:

```
<?php
  //Print the contents

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
  {
    $id=$row['msg_id'];
    title=$row['title'];
?>
   //data goes here                 
<?php
  } //while
?>
```

ok, so I have that, the problem then (sorry for so many circles) is that the data from `index.php` is being sent to result.php that is where the data is being output, using javascript I use `pagination.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //Display Loading Image
    function Display_Load()
    {
      $("#loading").fadeIn(900,0);
      $("#loading").html("<img src='bigLoader.gif' />");
    }
    //Hide Loading Image
    function Hide_Load()
    {
      $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
    };

    $("#pagination li:first").css({'color' : '#FF0084'}).css({'border' : 'none'});

    Display_Load();

    $("#results").load("pagination_data.php?page=1", Hide_Load());

    //Pagination Click
    $("#pagination li").click(function(){

      Display_Load();

      //CSS Styles
      $("#pagination li")
      .css({'border' : 'solid #dddddd 1px'})
      .css({'color' : '#0063DC'});

      $(this)
      .css({'color' : '#FF0084'})
      .css({'border' : 'none'});

      //Loading Data
      var pageNum = this.id;

      $("#results").load("pagination_data.php?page=" + pageNum, Hide_Load());
    });
  });
</script>
```

and in the top of `result.php` i have the following piece of code:

```
<?php
  include('config.php');
  $per_page = 9; 
  $sql = "select * from tabe where title='$data'";
  $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
  $count = mysql_num_rows($rsd);
  $pages = ceil($count/$per_page)
?>
```

So again what im trying to do is to make the form from `index.php` send me to `result.php` but also send the data to `pagination.php` sorry if this is very confused typed

Comment: have you tried including pagination.php in result.php and call whatever functions you need from there?

Comment: Note: The `mysql` library you are using has been deprecated and is removed from PHP. It only works now because you're running an outdated version PHP. When you/your host upgrades, your application will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first your form target should be called `result.php` not `result2.php`. And also I'm not sure but aren't you trying to return the data from `pagination_data.php`

As I understand your question, you are trying to implement a search that splits 100 results into 10 pages. So the server needs to safe the result of the search query you entered in case the user loads the next page!

In PHP you can achieve such things using Sessions, a Session stores data in php for multiple requests. 
(http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

```
//result.php
<?php
    //Start your session
    session_start();

    //Safe whatever you want
    $_SESSION['my_key'] = array('my', 'funny', 'data');

    //Or print stuff previously safed in the session
    echo $_SESSION['last'];
?>
```